# parsing website data with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

i want to extract a certain number from a site.

```
String1&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font style="color:#EE6564;" > 
112.674448 </font>&nbsp;handle <br/>

String2&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font style="color:#EE6564;" > 
60.90402 </font>&nbsp;handle  <br/>

String3&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font style="color:#EE6564;" > 
51.770428 </font>&nbsp;handle  <br/>

String4&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font style="color:#EE6564;" > 
182712 </font>&nbsp;handle  <br/>
```

i want to get the value after String1 which is 112.674448 but i can't seem to find a way.
i've tried

```
soup.findAll(text="String1&nbsp;:&nbsp;")
```

but that doesn't find anything as well as

```
soup.findAll(text="String1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can give a unique ID to font Tag and then you can do something like :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = \
"""
String1&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font style="color:#EE6564;" > 
112.674448 </font>&nbsp;handle <br/>

String2&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font id="font1" style="color:#EE6564;" > 
60.90402 </font>&nbsp;handle  <br/>

String3&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font style="color:#EE6564;" > 
51.770428 </font>&nbsp;handle  <br/>

String4&nbsp;:&nbsp; <font style="color:#EE6564;" > 
182712 </font>&nbsp;handle  <br/>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.findAll("font",id="font1")
```

Comment: that works great! sorry for being a noob, but how do i get the data that the tag holds?

Comment: for tag in soup.findAll("font",style="color:#EE6564;"):
        print tag.contents
    print tag.contents[2]  <- throws an error and  tag.contents[0] just prints the last line

Comment: Try this : `soup.findAll('font',id='font1')[0].contents[0].strip()`